# What is the difference between react-router and react-hash-router?

Tags: react-router

What is the main difference between `<Router>` and the `<Hash-router>` in react.js?

In my program, i put a form tag and mention a components path in action, but I used hash-router. I am not able to switch to "mentions component" but in case of router it switches to that other component.

Why is that, and what are the other difference between the two?

```
<HashRouter>
<div>
<h1>Simple SPA</h1>
<ul className="header">
<li><NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
<li><NavLink to="/stuff">Stuff</NavLink></li>
<li><NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
</ul>
<div className="content">
<Switch>
<Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
<Route path="/stuff" component={Stuff}/>
<Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
</Switch>
</div>
</div>
</HashRouter>
```

The form:

```
<form action='/stuff'>
<label for="firstName"><b>FirstName</b></label>
<input type="text" name="fname" /><br/><br/>

<label for="lastName"><b>LastName</b></label>
<input type="text" name="lname"/><br/><br/>

<button type="submit" align="right">Signup</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the main difference between <Router> and <HashRouter>  in react.js

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.